# не работает Clusterer в яндекс карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api

```
var myClusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer();
myClusterer.add(points);
myMap.geoObjects.add(myClusterer);
```

Содержимое points на скрине

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В вопросе недостаточно информации, что именно у вас не получилось или не работает. Попробуйте создать кластеризатор на основе примера: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_create

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса